# How do I find out the detailed format of an audio file?

Tags: audio, gstreamer

I am interested in very detailed information like:

- content-type (raw, ac3, etc)
- layout (interleaved/non interleaved)
- format (F32LE, F32BE, etc)

and other properties like those present in the list of [GStreamer types](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/pwg/html/section-types-definitions.html).

I have already tried but did not succeed with Windows Explorer Properties Details, [Gspot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) and [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use VLC, media properties (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>).

If it's not detailed enough then use ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i yourfile
```

Comment: Both ways don't seem to show the layout (interleaved/non interleaved).